# Data being cut off when importing from excel into SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

My datasource connection is now setup to use an excel file in SSRS. However once I import my data into SSRS, Text within one of my column's gets cut off at a certain point. So for instance I have a column that has comments and once those comments are beyond A certain length they cut off, however in my original excel sheet the full comments are there.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are exceeding a default character limit when exporting data from excel. Probably around the 255 character range. See the link for more information about a similar [problem](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/860660/Excel-source-having-more-than-255-characters).

Comment: This link explains for how to solve the problem using SSIS. Please explain how to do it in SSRS

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was solved [Here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1350620-364-1.aspx)
The file being imported had a .csv extension and that was causing SSIS to interpret it as related to Excel formatting with a limitation of 255 characters per column... regardless of how it was defined the field size in the import process. The fix was changing the import file's extension to .txt and modifying the Connection Manager to look for the file with the updated extension. Now when the field is imported with values less than and more than 255 characters, everything comes through. SSIS no longer associates the import file with Excel and automatically applies the expected limitations.